# Limiting result set by group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have couple of tables that are related in easiest case as 1:N; for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE X (id INTEGER, foo VARCHAR(16));
CREATE TABLE Y (id INTEGER, x_id INTEGER, bar VARCHAR(16));
```

and some data inside, like:

```
INSERT INTO X VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');
INSERT INTO Y VALUES
    (1, 1, 'blue'), (2, 1, 'green'), (3, 1, 'red'),
    (4, 2, 'big'), (5, 2, 'small'),
    (6, 3, 'car'), (7, 3, 'bike'), (8, 3, 'skate');
```

What I want to do: select entities from both tables limiting by `x.id`. For example, I need to select 2 entities, then this will not work properly:

```
SELECT x.id, x.foo, y.id, y.bar
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
LIMIT 2
```

Because if will apply limit to the final resulting row set, not basing on `x.id` . The result should be:

```
x.id x.foo y.id y.bar
 1    'a'   1  'blue'
 1    'a'   2  'green'
 1    'a'   3  'red'
 2    'b'   4  'big'
 2    'b'   5  'small'
```

My idea was to write some block-numerator, which will add "block" number to the result row set and then instead of `LIMIT` use `WHERE`, so:

```
SELECT block_number, x.id, x.foo, y.id, y.bar
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
WHERE block_number <= 2
```

But so far I did not find any good way to get that block number. "Good" means:

- Without sub-queries. Original selection may be quite complex and involves many tables, but it is fast as the joins are all through indexed fields. And I don't want to break performance
- Ideally, without new join-s. Some window-function may be the good solution since Postgres supports that

I tried to do stuff like:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.id), x.id, x.foo, y.id, y.bar
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
WHERE block_number <= 2
```

but, sadly, that provides the row number **in** block, not **per** block and therefore can not be used for my issue.

Also, selecting `x` records and limiting it "beforehand" in sub-query like this:

```
SELECT x.id, x.foo, y.id, y.bar
FROM 
  (SELECT x.id LIMIT 2) AS x
    INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
```

is not an option. It is because:

- Original query contains fields from all tables and I don't know for sure which one belong to which table. I can add some mechanism to determine that, but it will slow down the application. The initial query is dynamically-generated
- More, original query may contain `ORDER BY` clause which ruins this idea because I can not write proper `ORDER BY` for sub-query that is only for table `x`

So, **important addition** : the solution should respect original query order. Easiest way to illustrate is:

```
SELECT block_number, x.id, x.foo, y.id, y.bar
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
WHERE block_number <= 2
ORDER BY x.id DESC
```

should produce:

```
block_number x.id x.foo y.id y.bar
     1        3    'c'   6  'car'
     1        3    'c'   7  'bike'
     1        3    'c'   8  'skate'
     2        2    'b'   4  'big'
     2        2    'b'   5  'small'
```

I.e. blocks should be counted properly in order to keep original order. And, again, I can not predict the initial order as it's dynamically specified.

*P.S.*

*Sorry, for not providing sql fiddle to you. That resource is not working for me and it's so already for quite long time.*

*Also, my Postgres version is: `9.4`, so any "new" features that may allow to achieve my goal - can be applied.*

Comment: Can u just give ys desired out put? I didn't quite understand

Answer (score 3):

You can use the window function [`dense_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-window.html).
Window functions cannot be called in WHERE clause, so it has to be placed in a subquery:

```
SELECT xid, foo, yid, bar
FROM (
    SELECT 
        x.id xid, x.foo, y.id yid, y.bar,
        dense_rank() over (order by x.id) rank
    FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id
    ) sub
WHERE rank <= 2;

 xid | foo | yid |  bar  
-----+-----+-----+-------
   1 | a   |   1 | blue
   1 | a   |   2 | green
   1 | a   |   3 | red
   2 | b   |   4 | big
   2 | b   |   5 | small
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Looks good, but I found the issue - it does not respect initial `ORDER BY` properly. For instance, if original query had `ORDER BY x.id DESC` then this "rank" will also be from 3 to 1, not from 1 to 3. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The only way I think is to change `order by` in the window function.

Comment: Checked that it's also can't follow any other order. Basically it ruins this thing for me .. as if I didn't care about order, I could simply do as I've described in the second case. And I can't track order as it's dynamic. But either way, +1 for your help.